# Triumph whistle mod for KTM RC200

Tags: engine, motorcycle, triumph, ktm

I want the eargasmic whistle mod from the triumph lineup on my KTM  RC200. I know it's technically not possible as different camshafts are present.

Is there any other mediocre mod that can be done without damaging my bike too much?

Comment: Are you just trying to recreate the signature whistle that Triumphs have? Or a specific mod? A quick Google search didn't turn up a "Triumph whistle mod".

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: @justinm410 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5Wl6SByBbY

Comment: @DucatiKiller I know the sound, but that's on a triumph. I was asking if he was referring to a mod.

Answer (score 1):

Largely, it's the oil pump making the high pitched whir. To a lesser extent, in the following order fuel pump>>air induction>>tune of exhaust.

So, no it will never sound like a Triumph. From top to bottom, the engines are designed differently.

Answer (score 0):

**The whining sound you hear is your primary gear on the crank**

Triumph chose to use a straight cut primary gear on the crank and outer clutch basket.  This straight cut gear is the sound you are hearing.

Some manufacturers choose to put a bit of an angle or a spring loaded secondary gear to quiet things down a bit.  That's not the case here.

This isn't a sound that involves gasses in your intake manifold or head construction coupled with an odd exhaust design.

You can't just replicate this sound on a bike without advanced machining and money.

This sound isn't the rotor pump for the oil either.  They are very quite devices and are used in almost all modern motorcycles.

Comment: TriumphRat forum collectively would disagree with you. Also, assuming this, one would expect the tone to change with engine load rather just RPM alone.

Comment: @justinm410  Throw some links up into your post.   I used to work in Triumph/Honda/Yamaha shop and they would collectively disagree with you.  If you take out the entire clutch mechanism from the bike and start it, it doesn't make that sound.

Comment: I will later. Seeing as the whistle was significantly different on Gen 1 to Gen 2 to Gen 3 engines and the crank to clutch gear design didn't really change, this is pretty suspect. Ya know what did change though? The oil pump. Not to mention that the whistle comes from the other side of the engine IIRC... Doesn't add up.